# access variable out of class

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I want to access `username` variable in class `b` who created in class `a`.

```
class a():
def __init__(self):
    self.username = "amirhossein"
    self.passwd = 1234

class b():
    def __init__(self):
        self.amir = a.username
        print(self.amir)

b()
```

this code give me this error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'a' has no attribute 'username'
```

what should I do?

Comment: `a` is a *class*, you never create an *instance* with the username and passwd attributes.

Comment: I don't understand why you want this. Why not cut out `class a` and have `self.amir = "amirhossein"`

Comment: Why is `b` inside `a`? Is it deliberate?

Comment: [https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)

Comment: Please update the indentation of your code. Python is very sensitive to indentation, as are python programmers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to access variables that are in a class, you either need to make them class variables, or create an instance of that class and access that instance's variables.

Here's how you'd use class variables:

```
class a():
    username = "amirhossein"
    passwd = 1234
    def __init__(self):
       pass

class b():
    def __init__(self):
        self.amir = a.username
        print(self.amir)

b()
```

And here's how you could do it with instances:

```
class a():
    def __init__(self):
        self.username = "amirhossein"
        self.passwd = 1234

class b():
    def __init__(self, a_instance):
        self.amir = a_instance.username
        print(self.amir)

b(a())
```

Both of them have the same output - `amirhossein`.

Helpful reading: [Class vs Instance Variables](https://medium.com/python-features/class-vs-instance-variables-8d452e9abcbd)